# In Tastypie, what is the right way to override Resource.is_authorized() to implement row-level permissions

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've added row-level authorization to a Tastypie Resource as follows:

```
from tastypie.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from tastypie.http import HttpUnauthorized

class MyResource(ModelResources):
    ...
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
        super(MyResource, self).is_authorized(request, object)
        if object and (object.user != request.user):
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(response=HttpUnauthorized())
```

For brevity, I've left out the usual imports and only specified the imports that are relavant to the question.

My question is, is there a cleaner way to override `is_authorized` without having to import `ImmediateHttpResponse` and `HttpUnauthorized`? It seems to me that these are implementation details, and I should be able to simply return `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for tastypie 0.9.12 have a good example of this.

https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.12/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization

Here is the "read" part -- see the docs for the rest:

```
class UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization(Authorization):

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        # This assumes a ``QuerySet`` from ``ModelResource``.
        return object_list.filter(user=bundle.request.user)

    def read_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
        # Is the requested object owned by the user?
        return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user

    # DON'T FORGET TO IMPLEMENT METHODS FOR CREATE/UPDATE/DELETE as shown in the docs.
```

You'll notice that `UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization.read_detail()` returns True/False.  The `read_list` method will return an empty list, which is acceptable according to the docs, but you can also raise `Unauthorized` exception if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code is perfectly fine, but if you don't want to import the response classes then a cleaner way is to write an authorization class and use it in your Resource class

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
class RowLevelAuthorization(Authorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None):
        if object and (object.user != request.user):
            return False
        else:
            return True

class MyResource(ModelResources):
    class Meta:
        authorization = RowLevelAuthorization()
```

Comment: I can't find any reference to Authorization.is_authorized() anywhere in the Tastypie docs. Can you provide a link which validates this approach?

Comment: Here is the link to [Tastypie Docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/authentication_authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization) mentioning the approach.  
  
I am not sure if the `is_authorized` method has been removed/hid in the latest releases.

Answer (score 0):

For the long run, you're much better off integrating django-guardian into your application with an authorization class like the following :

https://gist.github.com/airtonix/5476453